# How to reduce an element's width by a pixel when it is defined in percent

Tags: html, css

I have four elements each of whom's width is set to `25%`.  They fill the width of the page perfectly.

I want to put a `1px` gap between each one. If I do this (`margin-right: 1px;` for example), the last element overflows onto the next line.  How can I reduce the width of each element by `1px` without calculating the width in pixels in the first place?

Comment: It's not elegant, but you could use negative margins to decrease the width by 1px (margin: auto -1px;) & set your padding to 1px. Won't work if you need your margins to collapse, though.

Comment: Box sizing might help you out: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Too bad you still can't do `width: 25%-1px`. That'll be the day!

Comment: You should do that in JavaScript. Take the `offsetWidth`, subtract 1 and set this as the abolute width (`style.width`).

Comment: @AlexDemchak I suppose the purists would object to having logic in a stylesheet... But it would certainly make things a lot easier in situations such as this!

Comment: @jangxx Using JS for styling will result in a FOUC, which is major :( and should be avoided whenever possible (else ppl start to rely on JS instead of CSS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just found a solution myself, with the help of @Lubnah in the comments.

```
.tab-list li {
  margin-right: -1px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.tab-list li:first-of-type {
  border-left: none;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't think about using border!

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS `calc` but its browser support is sketchy:

```
width: calc( 25% - 1px );
width: -moz-calc( 25% - 1px );
width: -webkit-calc( 25% - 1px );
```

Comment: This will be nice once it's widely supported…

Answer (score 0):

Width is calculated inside the container. Any padding or margins you set will be added to the width.

Set your width to 23% and your margin to 1%

Left margin (1) plus width (23) plus right margin (1) = 25. That, placed four times on the page will add up to 100.

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat slightly by having an inner div inside each element with width auto and margin-right:1px

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7R6zZ/

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">1</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">2</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">3</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">4</div>
</div>

.outer {
 width:25%;
 float:left;
}
.outer .inner {
 width:auto;
 margin-right:1px;
 background:#999;
 min-height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) and borders.

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
div {
  width: 25%;
  border-right: 1px solid right;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use box sizing as `box-sizing:border-box` 
and use 1px right border with same color as background

```
 .box{
      width:25%;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      border-right: 1px solid "same color as your background"
 }
```